# Sitecore SXA Search by Postcode or Location

Tags: sxa

We are currently working Sitecore 9.0.2 with SXA 1.8.1

I have a list of items(for example postcodes in London) inherits `IPOI` template.

Content

- Home
- PW1 - Latitude = xxx , Longitude = xxx
- W1 - Latitude = xxx , Longitude = xxx
- EY1 - Latitude = xxx , Longitude = xxx

I have added an SXA location finder and search results components on my page.

**Problem:** I select London in the location finder I want search results to populate all the 3 items as they are in london , at the moment it displays Zero results , Can i achieve this functionality OOTB with SXA Search components , if not an approach on how to solve? it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing things here a little bit. The Location Finder rendering is used to find a location. When you will put a "*London*" there is will go to Google and ask for the location for "*London*". After that, it will update the hash with an additional `g` parameter which will save that location. Later on, that location can be used to:

- search within a radius of e.g. 10 kilometres from that point
- sort results by distance from that point

So basically Location Finder translates the name of a location to geographical point (latitude and longitude).

What you are asking is more like a Search Box functionality. You put a word, like a city name (in that case "*London*") and you want to see points in that point. If your POI items would have for example `Location` text field, you can use Search Box to search for the content but that is not what you are aiming for.

The functionality which you are asking for - as far as I'm understanding it correctly - is not available out of the box.

You would need to implement custom logic which will:

1. Translate name of the city to a polygon - get the city boundaries
2. Check if any of your items are inside of those boundaries
3. Display only those items

That is not a trivial task but achievable!